# How do i get ride of this react native animation Moti error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using moti library for image animation in react native this error is thrown to me.

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[3], "moti").MotiImage')

Here is my code file

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { SIZES, images } from "../../constants";
import {MotiImage} from 'moti';

const Walkthrough2 = ({ animate }) => {
    console.log("Moti Images",MotiImage);
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, overflow:'hidden'}} >
           <Text>Walkthrough2:</Text>
        </View>
     );
  };

export default Walkthrough2;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 86,
    height: 102,
    zIndex: 0,
    borderRadius: SIZES.radius,
  },
});
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "MargaretEcommerceApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "android": "react-native run-android",
  "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "start": "react-native start",
  "test": "jest",
  "lint": "eslint ."
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
   "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
   "moti": "^0.17.1",
   "react": "17.0.2",
   "react-native": "0.67.3",
   "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
   "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.1",
   "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
   "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
   "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
   "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
   "eslint": "7.14.0",
   "jest": "^26.6.3",
   "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
   "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
   },
    "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
   }
  }
```

Please help me to solve it out Thankyou

Comment: Looks like a weird issue with some sort of config. Did you try clearing your cache and restarting the dev server?

Answer (score 0):

### Reason for Issue

Reanimated dependency "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0" as stated in the official documentation requires some additional configs, including babel, Hermes, and MainApplication.java to work properly with React Native.

I guess Reanimated ^2.0.0 is not yet supported on React Native ^0.64.0

### Solution NOTE

After making changes, make sure to clear gradle and yarn caches. Three changes needs to be made:

1. Add Reanimated's babel plugin to your babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = { ... plugins: [ ... 'react-native-reanimated/plugin', ], };
```

2. Turn on Hermes engine by editing android/app/build.gradle

```js
project.ext.react = [ enableHermes: true // <- here | clean and rebuild if changing ]
```

3. Plug Reanimated in MainApplication.java

```java
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage; // <- add

import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage; // <- add ...

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

...

@Override protected String getJSMainModuleName() {

return "index";

}

@Override protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {

return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add

}

};
```

I tried this but I still got the error: `cannot read property ‘useRef’ of null`

To resolve the useRef issue, you simply delete the node_modules and package-lock.json files, install node module using `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`, then run your application again.